# Installed "El Capitan"on my MacBook Air and now my computer doesn't recognize my printer

Tags: macos, printing

I had Mavericks on my MacBook Air previously. After installing "El Capitan", my printer isn't recognized anymore (it was before the upgrade). I added my printer to the "list of printers" again, but it still wouldn't print.

Need help with an easy to understand solution.

Comment: Please can you edit your question and add the model and brand of printer.

Comment: Please go to the website of the printer's manufacturer, whatever it is, and see if there are any updated drivers available for the printer.